# undefined reference to `PQclear' compiling simple 'C' program with Postgres 10 calls

Tags: c, postgresql

Simple C prog that compiles and runs on Debian Linux. I need to get it running on Windows, but get the following when I compile it. It seems to be a common problem but I haven't yet found a solution.

If I use

```
#include <libpq-fe.h>
```

I get

```
C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\cl>gcc -o test2 test2.c
test2.c:3:22: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libpq-fe.h>
```

If I use

```
#include "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\include\libpq-fe.h"
```

I get

```
C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\cl>gcc -o test2 test2.c
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `PQfinish'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `PQconnectdb'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `PQstatus'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `PQfinish'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x11f): undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x12f): undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x17c): undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x190): undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x1b1): undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x1ed): undefined reference to `PQnfields'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to `PQfname'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x26a): undefined reference to `PQgetvalue'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x2a6): undefined reference to `PQntuples'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x2b8): undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x2cc): undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x2dc): undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x2f0): undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x300): undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMue3l.o:test2.c:(.text+0x30c): undefined reference to `PQfinish'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Is it the first time you try to use a library?

Comment: How exactly do you build? Please show the equivalent commandlines or the makefile?

Comment: Yes, the first time (in fact the fist time I've done any C in windows!) - plus I'm not a C programmer....  The cmdline commands are in my original post.

Comment: How do you build? Do you use a compiler? Do you use an IDE? Tell us what you do between writing the text which is your program and running an executable. Have you successfully compiled and run a "HelloWorld"?

Comment: All this looks totally normal. You need the -I option to indicate where includes are, -L for where the libpq library is located, and -lpq to tell to link with libpq. BTW the same is true with Debian Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Here a simple program that additionally to including the header file also queries a table *test* in a schema *test* which has two fields *firstname* and *lastname*. This makes sure that not only the include file is found but also the linker finds the additional libraries:

**Simple test program**

```
#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int lib_ver = PQlibVersion();
    printf("PQlibVersion: %d\n", lib_ver);

    PGconn *conn = PQconnectdb("user=stephan password=mypwd dbname=postgres");
    if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {        
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't connect to Postgres: %s\n", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQfinish(conn);
        exit(-1);
    }

    PGresult *res = PQexec(conn, "SELECT * FROM test.test");    
    if (PQresultStatus(res) == PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
        printf("\n     %-10s %-10s\n", PQfname(res, 0), PQfname(res, 1));
        printf("-------------------------\n");
        int rows = PQntuples(res);    
        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {       
            printf("[%d]: %-10s %-10s\n", i, PQgetvalue(res, i, 0), PQgetvalue(res, i, 1));
        }   
    }       
    PQclear(res);
    PQfinish(conn);
    return 0;
}
```

**Build**

This can be build by the following command line:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -I "C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\include" -L "C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\lib" query.c -lpq -o query
```

**Output of test run**

[image: output of test run]

**Explanation of compiler arguments**

```
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    argumet   |                meaning                                               |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   -Wall      |  switches on many warnigs                                            |
|   -Wextra    |  switches on additional warnings like unused parameters              |
|   -I _xxx_   |  searches for additional include files in the directory _xxx_                   |
|   -L _yyy_   |  looks in directory _yyy_ for additional libraries                   |
|   -l_zz_     |  links library _zz_                                                  |
|   -o _name_  |  the resulting program is called _name_.exe instead of a.exe         |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Order of libraries**

The order is important when linking against libraries. To avoid *undefined reference* errors, the -lpq argument should come after the .c source files.

**How to find include and lib directories?**

The following commands are printing out the include and lib directory for Postgres:

```
pg_config --includedir
pg_config --libdir
```

Alternatively use Window File Explorer, navigate to the installation directory of Postgres and search for the *include* and *lib* directories.

Comment: Looks very promising, but I now get  (note the forward slash) - there;s some very old threads I've found that mention it, but no answers. I thought it was just me that got confused between linux and windows... C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\lib/libpq.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I've omitted to say I'm using MinGW (easiest way to get GCC installed that I could find)

Comment: _File format not recognized_ could be an indicator that there is a 32-bit/64-bit mismatch between gcc / Postgres / Windows version. Can this be the case?

Comment: I think it's just the fwd slash instead of the backslash in the path. But I could be wrong!.

Comment: I often see in software that is mainly developed on *NIX systems, that diagnostic output often mixes backslashes and forward slashes. Therefore this is presumably not the problem.
Also found this: 
https://github.com/pgmodeler/pgmodeler/issues/695
Here somebody has a 32-bit Windows and a 64-bit version of Postgres with the same error message you have encountered. So might be worth to check.

Comment: I get the same eror:  C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\lib/libpq.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status     I've now installed Cygwin (didn't work yesterday, OK today!) and get the same error. File confirms i's a 64bit DLL.

Comment: You can quickly check on the command line with _wmic os get osarchitecture_ what kind of Windows OS (32-bit/64-bit) you are running. What is the output?

Comment: It's 64bit Win10.

Comment: What's the output of _uname -m_ ?

Comment: In CygWin $ uname -m
x86_64

Comment: Made a test with Cygwin on Windows 10 x64. Used the info under _Install Required Cygwin Packages_ from here  http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/ to install it. Worked. Adopted screenshots. Regarding the _File format not recognized_ I'm out of ideas unfortunately.